# Why does my webserver try to install php7.4 when I have 7.3 running?

Tags: debian, apt, php

On apt upgrade I get the notification that new packages will be installed

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libicu65 libapache2-mod-php7.4 libonig4 php7.4 php7.4-bz2 php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-curl php7.4-dev php7.4-fpm php7.4-gd php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-mysql php7.4-opcache
```

However my webserver runs php7.3-fpm and I am not upgrading right now because the framework I am using is not tested for 7.4. Why is it trying to update to 7.4? And why libapache2-mod-php7.4 in particular?

I also fail to set the packages on hold since it's always selecting the one or the other

```
apt-mark hold php7.4-common php7.4 libicu65
libicu65 was already set on hold.
php7.4-common set on hold.
php7.4 set on hold.

apt-mark showhold
php7.4
php7.4-common

apt-mark hold php7.4-common php7.4 libicu65
php7.4-common was already set on hold.
php7.4 was already set on hold.
libicu65 set on hold.

apt-mark showhold
libicu65
```

Comment: An experimental package doesn't appear out of thin air. There has to be experimental sources defined on your system. https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian . For now it appears to be at least a mix of Debian 9 oldstable (9.12), Debian 10 stable (php 7.3) and experimental (libicu65)

Comment: @A.B worse than just being defined because it won't install from the experimental repo by default, even when added to sources (manual priority adjust is needed, or an explicit install)

Comment: My advice would be to do a clean reinstall of Debian 10. Trying to move everything to Debian 10 stable is possible, but prone to errors (missing files caused by complex downgrades, mass removal of packages by mistake etc.). Anyway your question doesn't reflect reality: your server is not running Debian stable (nor Debian oldstable), but a frankendebian.

Comment: Yes true, the php sources are from Surý since I need 7.3 and stable did not have it. I can not switch to 10 without testing yet. So how can I solve the hold problem?

Comment: What is your sources.list and/or sources.list.d have in them?

Comment: packages.sury.org/php/ and Debian stable

Comment: @Supertyp I am thinking that the non-Debian php repo is the cause of your issues.